# Regex to remove multiple html nested tags

Tags: java, html, regex, formatting

I am having html sting like:

```
<p dir="ltr">hello boys <b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>n</b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>o</b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>w</b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b> </b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b>b</b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b>o</b></b></b></b><b><b><b>l</b></b></b><b><b>d</b></b><b> </b></p>
```

I want to keep the `<p dir="ltr">`tag, one `<b></b>` containing all single bold characters.

The result should be:

```
<p dir="ltr">hello boys <b>now bold</b></p>
```

The number of  `<b></b>` will not be fixed

What regex can be followed in Java in order to do the same. Italics and underline will also be present other than bold

If, the text has all 3 types of formatting say, bold, italic and underline together, the generated html is:

```
<p dir="ltr"><b><b><b><b>bold</b></b></b></b> <i><i><i><i><i><i><i><i>italic</i></i></i></i></i></i></i></i><i> </i>normal <u><u><u><u><u><u><u><u>underline</u></u></u></u></u></u></u></u> <b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b>all</b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b> </b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><u><b>together</b></u></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></p>
```

After applying the regex suggested by traianus the output of this becomes (I have applied the formatting for bold, italics and underline):

```
<p dir="ltr"><b>bold</b> <i>italic</i> normal <u>underline all together</u></p>
```

So, **underline all together** should have b, i and u tags all together in order to show the proper formatting.

The code:

```
String htmlString=Html.toHtml(mainEditText.getText());
        String boldRemoval = htmlString.replaceAll("<b>([a-z]*)</b>", "#$1#").replaceAll("(<b>|</b>)", "").replaceAll("#(.*)#", "<b>$1</b>").replaceAll("#", "");
        String italicRemoval = boldRemoval.replaceAll("<i>([a-z]*)</i>", "#$1#").replaceAll("(<i>|</i>)", "").replaceAll("#(.*)#", "<i>$1</i>").replaceAll("#", "");
        String underlineRemoval = italicRemoval.replaceAll("<u>([a-z]*)</u>", "#$1#").replaceAll("(<u>|</u>)", "").replaceAll("#(.*)#", "<u>$1</u>").replaceAll("#", "");
        Log.d("solution", underlineRemoval);
```

Comment: You can't. use an html parser and extract the text content from the parent b tag and consecutive b tags, then concatenate and replace.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte any sample code or tutorial would have helped a lot

Comment: That's the wrong use case for regex. I think jsoup may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @nerdwaller how to go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = s.replaceAll("(</?(?:b|i|u)>)\\1+", "$1").replaceAll("</(b|i|u)><\\1>", "");
```

Comment: If the html has some text which has all bold, italics and underline styling, then all the extra tags are remaining. How can that be handled? Please refer question for example

Comment: can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624627/add-a-new-html-tag-to-an-html-string-in-android/26654189#26654189

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840538/re-factor-html-structure

Comment: Please look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699742/sanitize-html-string any help will be great

Answer (score 2):

If you relax your problem to allow multiple-round replacements (like Casimir said), and suppose, that # character is not allowed in the input, something like this could help:

`String test = "<p dir=\"ltr\">hello boys <b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>n</b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>o</b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>w</b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b> </b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b>b</b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b>o</b></b></b></b><b><b><b>l</b></b></b><b><b>d</b></b><b> </b></p>";`

`String solution = test.replaceAll("<b>([a-z]*)</b>", "#$1#").replaceAll("(<b>|</b>)", "").replaceAll("#(.*)#", "<b>$1</b>").replaceAll("#", ""));`

Comment: You saved my day, everything works. But, if the html has some text which has all bold, italics and underline styling, then only underline tag is remaining and the rest are disappearing. How can that be handled?

Comment: Please send an example.

Comment: If you have many different nested tags (`<b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b>`), filtering this out is a real pain with regexp. In this situation you should choose another approach, as the others said.

Comment: yes, then what should be done?

Comment: what approach do you think will be appropriate?

Comment: html parser, or write your our parser that collects all the outer formatting tags of a text.

Comment: hey, I have noticed something, if there is an anchor tag in the html content, then the bold tag is not getting closed, otherwise everything is working fine, can you please take a look at it? <p dir="ltr"><i>italic</i> <b>bold <u>underline</u> <a href="jEvWeOlplk"><font color ="</b>009a49">Prashant Ghimire</font></a></p>

Comment: This `<font color ="</b>009a49">` is evil for regexp, because it doesn't know that the </b> is in an attribute value. This is another argument to use a correct html parser with the possibility to handle this issues.

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624627/add-a-new-html-tag-to-an-html-string-in-android/26654189#26654189

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840538/re-factor-html-structure

Answer (score 0):

```
 String s = "<p dir=\"ltr\">hello boys <b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>n</b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>o</b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>w</b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b> </b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b>b</b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b>o</b></b></b></b><b><b><b>l</b></b></b><b><b>d</b></b><b> </b></p>";
    while (!s.equals(s = s.replaceAll("<b><b>([^<>]+)</b></b>", "<b>$1</b>"))) {
    }
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("</b><b>", ""));
```