# Add a new html tag to an html string in android

Tags: java, android, html, regex, jsoup

I have a string obtained from an EditText. The string contains html tags.

```
Spannable s  = mainEditText.getText();
String webText = Html.toHtml(s);
```

The contents of the string is :

```
<p dir="ltr">test</p> 
<p dir="ltr"><img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-0de7a730-3fa9-4a1e-9f82-d34e4f6e2d31-file" /><br /></p> 
<p dir="ltr"><a href="22.572646,88.363895"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=22.572646,88.363895&zoom=15&size=960x540&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:!%7C22.572646,88.363895" /></a><br /> </p>
```

**Now, what I want to do is, wherever there is an img src tag, I want to precede it with a center tag.**

What should I do to get the following output?

```
<p dir="ltr">test</p> 
<p dir="ltr"><center><img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-0de7a730-3fa9-4a1e-9f82-d34e4f6e2d31-file" /></center><br /></p> 
<p dir="ltr"><a href="22.572646,88.363895"><center><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=22.572646,88.363895&zoom=15&size=960x540&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:!%7C22.572646,88.363895" /></center></a><br /> </p>
```

Can a regex solve the issue or should it be done in a different way?

Can JSOUP help in any way? Is there any other type of HTML parser which can do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the JSOUP solution suggested by [mourphy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356671/mourphy). But, I had edited the method a little and it did the miracle for me. The new method is:

```
public String wrapImgWithCenter(String html){
     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        doc.select("img").wrap("<center></center>");
        return doc.html();
}
```

Thanks mourphy and vks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
(<img\s+[^>]*>)
```

You can try this.Replace with `<center>$1</centre>`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/38

Something like

```
var re = /(<img\s+[^>]*>)/g;
var str = '<p dir="ltr">test</p> \n<p dir="ltr"><img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-0de7a730-3fa9-4a1e-9f82-d34e4f6e2d31-file" /><br /></p> \n<p dir="ltr"><a href="22.572646,88.363895"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=22.572646,88.363895&zoom=15&size=960x540&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:!%7C22.572646,88.363895" /></a><br /> </p>';
var subst = '<center>$1</centre>';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: could not understand the demo properly. can you please show me a java code or tell me how to use the online regex tester?

Comment: thanks, saw the output. I could see the center tag start but it does not have a closing tag............can anything be done about that?

Comment: webText = webText.replaceAll("(?=<img\\s+)", "<center>"); is removing the img tag closer also...........the output is <p dir="ltr">huh</p>
<p dir="ltr"><center><img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-7b1f891b-eea2-4c95-87e1-11ff10a9ba12-file"><br>
</p>
you can see that the closing slash "/" of img tag is also gone

Comment: the regex is giving an error saying invalid escape sequence in java

Comment: output is having extra p tags and center tags misplaced <p dir="ltr">test again</p> 
<p dir="ltr"></p>
<center>
 <img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-1b471789-4bc7-422c-8ebb-083d01078eb0-file" />
 <p></p> 
 <p dir="ltr"></p>
 <center>
  <a href="28.635308,77.22496"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=28.635308,77.22496&zoom=15&size=960x540&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:!%7C28.635308,77.22496" /></a>
  <br /> 
  <p></p> 
 </center>
</center>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63847/discussion-between-kittu88-and-vks).

Comment: do you have any idea of JSOUP? I could not figure out the regex..................

Comment: @kittu88 you can check demo and modify it acc to your needs :) i got no idea about jsup

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795112/remove-extra-a-href-tag-from-html-string

Comment: I have posted a new question, as discussed I am posting the link to it http://stackoverflow.com/q/26800506/1627599 please take a look at it

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840538/re-factor-html-structure

Answer (score 1):

By using Jsoup, you can use the [wrap()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#wrap(java.lang.String)) method of the `Element` class of Jsoup.

It would look like this :

```
public String wrapImgWithCenter(String html) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    doc.getElementsByTag("img").wrap("<center></center>");
    return doc.html();
}
```

Comment: It is creating some extra p tags and the image is no more inside a p tag <html>
<p dir="ltr"> </p>
<center> 
 <img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/bcff7108-cbce-4ab8-b5d1-1f82827e6519/tfss-1922cdc7-e62d-4257-998c-b461eb6f4880-file" /> 
</center>
<p></p> 
<p dir="ltr"> </p>
<center> 
 <a href="28.635308,77.22496"><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=28.635308,77.22496&zoom=15&size=960x540&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:!%7C28.635308,77.22496" /></a> 
</center>
<br /> 
<p></p>
</html>

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795112/remove-extra-a-href-tag-from-html-string

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840538/re-factor-html-structure

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex, you could also do this in java:

```
String formatted = str.replaceAll("(<img\\s+[^>]*>)", "<center>$1</center>");
```