# Sanitize HTML string

Tags: java, android, html, replaceall

I have an HTML sting like:

```
<p dir="ltr"><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u>bold</u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u> </u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u>all</u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u> </u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u>in</u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u> </u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u><b><i><u>one</u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></u></i></b></p>
```

I want to sanitize the html like `<b><i><u> bold all in one </b></i></u>`

I tried this method:  `webText = webText.replaceAll("(</?(?:b|i|u)>)\\1+", "$1").replaceAll("</(b|i|u)><\\1>", "");`

But it is of no use. The html remains clumsy. What should I do to mend the same? Is there any other Regex or JSON way?

Comment: Don't use regexes to parse HTML.  Use an HTML parser.

Comment: @ajb I thought about JSOUP but could not implement it right. If you have some idea about JSOUP or something else..........can you please post some code to sort this out?

Comment: I haven't actually used it.  Hopefully someone else knows something about JSOUP or another library.

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502759/how-to-strip-or-escape-html-tags-in-android

Comment: @samgak that removes all html tags which is not expected

Answer (score 1):

> But it is of no use. The html remains clumsy. What should I do to mend
>   the same? Is there any other Regex or JSON way?

Regex *may* help here, but in general they serve not very well as Html parser if things get complex. Jsoup is a *great* Html library, and i really can recommend it.

Unfortunately your html is still valid html, so  the solution is tricky.

Best you start with the [Jsoup documentation](http://jsoup.org/), especially the one of it's [Selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Here's something for starting:

```
final String html = ... // your html from above

// Parse the html string into a document
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());

/*
 * Select all elements, which ...
 * 
 *   (a) have a text (= at least not empty)
 *   (b) has no childs it's own
 * 
 * Iterate over those found and print them.
 */
for( Element element : doc.select("*:matches(^..+?$):not(:has(*))") )
{
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

**Result:**

```
<u>bold</u>
<u>all</u>
<u>in</u>
<u>one</u>
```

If you need literally `<b><i><u> bold all in one </b></i></u>`:

```
final String html = ... // your html from above

// As above
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());

// All text of the document
String text = doc.text();

// Create an element and it's childs
Element element = new Element(Tag.valueOf("b"), "");
element.appendElement("i").appendElement("u").text(text);

System.out.println(element);
```

**Result:**

```
<b><i><u>bold all in one</u></i></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try below method to remove unwanted html tags:

```
public String stripHtml(String html) 
{
    return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
}
```

Comment: this will remove all html tags, valid or invalid!